# Работа с api, не пойму как реализовать запрос

Tags: python-3.x, windows

Вот документация:

```
https://ngrok.com/docs#start-tunnel
```

Вот мой код:

```
url = "http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels" # Сам сервис я запустил у себя
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
data = {"proto":"http","addr":"80"}
response = requests.post(url,data=data,headers=headers)
print (response.content)
```

В выводе получаю:

```
b'{"status_code":400,"msg":"failed to deserialize request parameter","details":{
"err":"invalid character \'p\' looking for beginning of value"}}\n'
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Заголовок `Content-type` точно нужен?

Comment: Вроде да, если убрать Content-type, то в выводе будет; b'{"status_code":415,"msg":"unsupported request Content-Type","details":{"availa
ble":["application/json","text/xml","application/xml"],"content-type":"applicati
on/x-www-form-urlencoded"}}\n'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = json.dumps({"proto":"http","addr":"80", "name": "tunnel-name"})
```